# jquery scrollTop is not working on samsung note 800

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

We have two div containers, on scroll of each we are automatically scrolling other div using 'scrollTop'.

However this scrollTop doesnt work in Samsung Note 800 but remaning all devices its working fine.

Please suggest if any alternative is there for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jqm, try with:

[jQuery.mobile.silentScroll()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/)

Scroll to a specific div:

```
 $.mobile.silentScroll($('YOUR_DIV').offset().top);
```

Comment: I have to scroll specific div element. silentScorll doesnt work on element i guess.